# Is this a valid date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, weekday

my function returns the selected date of a calendar in this format:

```
var returnValue = "6.7.2017"; //day.month.year
```

When i try to use it for a new Date, it does not work:

```
var weekdays = ['Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag'];
var wkdayname = new Date(returnValue); //Error: returnValue ist NaN
var dayName = weekdays[wkdayname.getDay()];
```

All I want is just the name of the weekday of this date.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: have to ask: did you return the `returnValue`? because `new Date('6.7.2017')` seems to work

Comment: This is working fine. Date supports the format you are providing. Can you share your code?

Comment: Try `new Date(returnValue.replace(/\./g, '-'))`. If you are open for library, you should use moment.js. Then you can do `moment(returnValue, "MM.DD.YYYY")`. You can also try `new Date(Date.parse(returnValue))`

Comment: your mask date is not valid for javascript "d.m.yyyy"

Comment: Check the reference to `new Date` to format correctly the constructor  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The date format also has the day and month switched from the format that `Date()` recognizes. This function transforms a date string using `.` and day first notation to the valid format:

```js
function transformDate (date){
 var day_month_year = date.split(".")
    return [day_month_year[1],day_month_year[0],day_month_year[2]].join("/")
} 

var returnValue = "6.7.2017"; //This is a string

var weekdays = ['Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag'];
var wkdayname = new Date(transformDate(returnValue)); 
var dayName = weekdays[wkdayname.getDay()];
alert(dayName)
```

Comment: this solution works absolutely fine in Firefox! Thank you!

Comment: There are many, many duplicates. You should avoid the parser completely, using the built-in parser is fraught. Parsing a string to format another string that is parsed by the built-in parser doesn't make a lot of sense. Just parse the string and give the parts to the Date constructor.

Comment: Yeah... i dont know how^^

Answer (score -1):

You can validate a date string using the `Date.parse()` API.

But mind you, this API's validation is a bit loose as it accepts both `ISO 8601` or `RFC 2822` date formats. If it is a valid `date` then the API returns you the `epoch time` which can then be used for creating the Javascript `Date` object. Otherwise it returns `NaN`.

As for getting the `day` - you can use the `.getDay()` API.

Example:

```js
if (Date.parse("aaabbcc")) {
    console.log("aaabbcc is Valid");
}
else {
    console.log("aaabbcc is invalid");
}

if (Date.parse("6.7.2017")) {
    var date = new Date(Date.parse("6.7.2017"));
    console.log("6.7.2017 is Valid");
    console.log("The day of the week is => " + date.getDay());
}
else {
    console.log("6.7.2017 is invalid");
}
```

**References:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: See the advice in your second reference: "*It is not recommended to use Date.parse … There are still many differences in how different hosts parse date strings, therefore date strings should be manually parsed*".